# prefetch to a specific level of cache

Tags: c

GCC has `__builtin_prefetch` to support prefetching. My question is how can I prefetch the data to a specific level of cache. For example, I only would like to prefetch the data to `L2 cache` instead of all the way to `L1 cache`.

Comment: Yeh, and pre-fetch only even bits ... :)

Comment: In general you can't. Most CPU architectures do not even support this kind of explicit cache management.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[__builtin_prefetch](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.6/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) has three arguments; the third one is the cache level. AFAICT, this has only effect on SSE, where it generates prefetchnta, prefetcht1, prefetcht2, prefetcht3, respectively.